# Lollipop RippleDrawable to TextView

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, textview, rippledrawable

drawable-v21/ripple.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:color="@color/colorAccent">
    <item
        android:drawable="@android:color/white"/>
</ripple>
```

TextView:

```
<TextView
     android:id="@+id/tv_back"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
     android:clickable="true"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:minWidth="200dp"
     android:text="@string/back_to_school"
     android:textColor="@color/color_sign_status"
     android:textSize="16sp"/>
```

If I want to set `RippleDrawable` to the `TextView`, I must set `android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"`, but how to set my custom background?

Or just to set background by the way:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_sign_tip"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
         android:id="@+id/tv_back"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
         android:clickable="true"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:minWidth="200dp"
         android:text="@string/back_to_school"
         android:textColor="@color/color_sign_status"
         android:textSize="16sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

If I use a `Button`, this is the result:

[image]

This is terrible. Is there any other way?

Comment: `android:background="@drawable/ripple"` ?

Comment: i know what the problem is.TextView just set "android:clickable" to true,Ripple always can work,then you can set background youself.

Answer (score 1):

I think this can help you:
You have to set your button's background to a RippleDrawable which you can define in XML. (I'll name it holo_blue_ripple.xml)

```
<item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"/> <!-- normal color -->
```

Then reference it with android:background="@drawable/holo_blue_ripple"